# string array error while compiling

Tags: c++, string

This is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include "MQmessage.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // declaring an array to store name/value pair
    struct Property  user_property[15];
    const char* const list[] = {"stateCode","errorCode"};
    const size_t len = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        strcpy(user_property[0].name,list[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        std::cout<<user_property[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting follwoing errors in the code:

> no match for 'operator<<' in std::cout

Can someone tell me what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: std::cout<<user_property[i].name<<endl; ???

Comment: The main problem is as described by the answers below, but as an aside note: In the `strcpy` call you refer to `user_property[0]` independent of the value of `i`. Also, there are always 15 `Property` objects, independent of `len`. Finally, I hope the constructor of `Property` allocates sufficient space in `name` for the `strcpy` to work without problems.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want `std::cout<<user_property[i].name<<endl`, otherwise you'll have to overload the `<<` operator of `Property`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload `operator<<` for `struct Property`.

Please note, that if you want to output just `Property::name` and it is `std::string` you also need to `#include <string>` to make `operator<<` for `std::string` available.

Comment: If `std::string` is a member of `Property` the header will already be included. However, they're using `strcpy` so it probably isn't a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a printing function for the "Property" like this one :

```
void print()
{
    std::cout<<this->name<<endl;
    std::cout<<this->othermember<<endl;  //if you have some other members
}
```

and in your main just do the following:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    user_property[i].print(); }
```